# ExpansionTile Flutter change tiltle position

Tags: flutter

[image][image]I want first ExpansionTile's item open title stay up side default, How can I do my title stays down side and Can you recomend another package. Customize has to be down. I used ExpansionTile Widget.

Comment: The question isn't very clear, can you upload a picture of what exactly you are trying to achieve or a code sample?

Comment: Thank you answer I uploaded picture. when open expanded panel custimized title has to be down

Comment: Please DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code.

Comment: Thank you your advice I can try to do as you said. I resolved this problem with visible Widget